# Strange MEF behavior with metadata interface

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, mef

I have encountered a very strange behavior of `GetExports<T,TMetadata>()`.

I have the following code:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = true), MetadataAttribute]
public class ControllerExportAttribute : ExportAttribute, IControllerMetadata
{

    public ControllerExportAttribute(Type controllerType, SessionStateBehavior controllerSessionStateBehavior)
        : base(typeof(IController))
    {
        ControllerSessionStateBehavior = controllerSessionStateBehavior;
        ControllerName = controllerType.Name;
    }

    public ControllerExportAttribute(Type controllerType)
        : this(controllerType, SessionStateBehavior.Default)
    {

    }

    public string ControllerName { get; private set; }
    public SessionStateBehavior ControllerSessionStateBehavior { get; private set; }
}

public interface IControllerMetadata
{
    //string ControllerName { get; }
    //SessionStateBehavior ControllerSessionStateBehavior { get; }
}
```

And I have the following line to import the controllers using the attribute:

```
var exportedControllers = ServiceLocator.Container.GetExports<IController, IControllerMetadata>();
```

Now to the strange thing. If i remove the comment from the fields in the interface, the import doesn't work.

Maybe I'm missing something....

Comment: I did missed something. `AllowMultiple = false` makes is work. And with `AllowMultiple = true`, the properties in the interface should be `IEnumerable<T>`.